# How to init a class static variable with Future in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

As we know, there is a `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` function that returns a `Future<Directory>` in package `path_provider`.
But now I want to init a static variable through it:

```
class Settings {
  static final Directory rootDirectory = /*The documents directory*/;
}
```

I can't use `await` here. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

use like this pathprovider depend on each platform code you need use await method .Dont initialize provider (if you can reduce ) on every class or widget .initialize this main method and use everywhere

```
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
//use like this pathprovider depend on each platform code you need use await method .Dont initialize pathproviderclass on every class or widget .initialize this main method and use everywhere
      var pa = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      settings.rootDirectory = pa;
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class settings {
      static late final Directory? rootDirectory;
    }
```